# How exactly works the Spring RowCallbackHandler? Can I use it to automatically create a txtfile from the ResultSet obtain performing a query?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using **JdbcTemplate** and the **RowMapper** interface to perform a query, obtain a list of rows and map these rows on object. It works fine, in the specific I have:

1. **DatiPianiInterventiDaoImpl** that is my DAO implementation

   public class DatiPianiInterventiDaoImpl implements DatiPianiInterventiDao {

   ```
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

    @Override
    public List<DatiPianiInterventiDto> getPianiInterventiList() {
        System.out.println("Into getPianiInterventiList()");

        String SQL = "select enteBeneficiario.COD_IST_ENT, intervento.COD_CUP, intervento.DES_TIT_INT, intervento.IMP_FIN_MIN, anagraficaRup.DES_COG_RUP, anagraficaRup.DES_NOM_RUP, anagraficaRup.FLG_SES, anagraficaRup.DAT_NAS, anagraficaRup.COD_COM, anagraficaRup.COD_FIS_RUP, anagraficaRup.DES_IND_EMA_RUP, anagraficaRup.COD_NUM_TEL, assocEnteBenRup.DES_DEC_NOM\r\n" + 
                "from TID023_INTERVENTO intervento\r\n" + 
                "INNER JOIN TID031_PIANO piano ON(intervento.PRG_INT = piano.PRG_INT )\r\n" + 
                "INNER JOIN TID022_ANAGRAFICARUP anagraficaRup ON(anagraficaRup.PRG_RUP = intervento.PRG_RUP)\r\n" + 
                "INNER JOIN TID018_ENTEBENEFICIARIO enteBeneficiario ON enteBeneficiario.COD_ENT = intervento.COD_ENT\r\n" + 
                "INNER JOIN TID019_ASSOCENTEBENRUP assocEnteBenRup ON assocEnteBenRup.PRG_RUP = intervento.PRG_RUP AND assocEnteBenRup.COD_ENT = intervento.COD_ENT \r\n" + 
                "where intervento.COD_TIP_STA_INT = 2 and piano.COD_TIP_BAN = 2 AND assocEnteBenRup.COD_TIP_NOM = 2;";

        System.out.println("QUERY: " + SQL);

        List<DatiPianiInterventiDto> datiPianiInterventoList = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new DatiPianiInterventiDtoMapper());

        return datiPianiInterventoList;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
        this.dataSource = ds;
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(ds);

    }
   ```

   }

As you can see this class contains the **getPianiInterventiList()** method that perform a query returning a list of **DatiPianiInterventiDto** objects.

So the **DatiPianiInterventiDto** represent a single row of the **ResultSet** returned by the query and these rows are mapped on the **DatiPianiInterventiDto** object by:

2. **DatiPianiInterventiDtoMapper** class that implements the Spring **RowMapper** interface:

   public class DatiPianiInterventiDtoMapper implements RowMapper {

   ```
    @Override
    public DatiPianiInterventiDto mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        DatiPianiInterventiDto oggettoCorrente = new DatiPianiInterventiDto();

        oggettoCorrente.setCodIstEnt(rs.getString("COD_IST_ENT"));
        oggettoCorrente.setCodCup(rs.getString("COD_CUP"));
        oggettoCorrente.setDesTitInt(rs.getString("DES_TIT_INT"));
        oggettoCorrente.setImpFinMin(rs.getBigDecimal("IMP_FIN_MIN"));
        oggettoCorrente.setDesCogRup(rs.getString("DES_COG_RUP"));
        oggettoCorrente.setDesNomRup(rs.getString("DES_NOM_RUP"));
        oggettoCorrente.setFlgSes(rs.getString("FLG_SES"));
        oggettoCorrente.setDatNas(rs.getDate("DAT_NAS"));
        oggettoCorrente.setCodCom(rs.getString("COD_COM"));
        oggettoCorrente.setCodFisRup(rs.getString("COD_FIS_RUP"));
        oggettoCorrente.setDesIndEmaRup(rs.getString("DES_IND_EMA_RUP"));
        oggettoCorrente.setCodNumTel(rs.getString("COD_NUM_TEL"));
        oggettoCorrente.setDesDecNom(rs.getString("DES_DEC_NOM"));

        return oggettoCorrente;
    }
   ```

   }

Ok, it works fine and so I obtain my list of objects.

Now my problem is that I have to create a textual file containing the textual content of all properties of all the **DatiPianiInterventiDto** objects in this list. Each object in the previous list have to create a new row in my textual file and each field is separated by the next one using the **|** character, something like:

```
FIELD 1 VALUE|FIELD 2 VALUE|FIELD 3 VALUE|FIELD 4 VALUE|FIELD 5 VALUE
```

So I know that I can simply create a new textual file, iterate on the list and write a new line in this file for each **DatiPianiInterventiDto** object in this list.

But from what I have understand Spring provide me the **RowCallbackHandler** interface to create a textual file directly from the **ResultSet** obtained from a query execution. It according at [RowCallbackHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html)

So my question is: instead to manually create a new textual file, iterate on my lit of **DatiPianiInterventiDto** objects and for each object create a row in this textual file, can I use this **RowCallbackHandler** to achieve this requirement?

How can I do it? And how can I handle the requirement that every field have to be separated from the next one using the **|** character?

Comment: The callback handler would do basically the same thing as what you're doing in the mapper, except it would write every field to a Writer: `writer.write(rs.getString("COD_IST_ENT")); writer.write("|"); writer.write(rs.getString("COD_CUP")); ...`

Comment: @JBNizet ok, but how can I save it on a file?

Comment: By making sure the writer writes to a file: `Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("thefile.txt"));`. Read the Java IO tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: And consider to specify an encoding (`UTF-8` for an example). :)

Comment: @JBNizet I am trying to insert your code to create the Writer object but Eclipse give me the following error message: "Multiple markers at this line
 - The value of the field DatiPianiInterventiRowCallbackHandler.writer is not used
 - Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit" Why?

Comment: I have no idea what your code looks like if you don't post it. But the FileWriter constructor throws a checked IOException, so you must handle it (throw it or catch it). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/